# Issue with part of CSS not loading HTML

Tags: php, css, html

******UPDATE********

Thank you for your help.  This has been very frustrating.

In order to try and show you where I am having issues, I just created 2 pages to show what is going on.

http://www.kolosse.org/stack/border

http://www.kolosse.org/stack/fail

border is partially what I am going for.  Not complete, but a start.  And oddly enough, using CSS. but just inline on the table tag.

Fail is what I am seeing.  Most of the code below is taken (in part) from the files that have made up "fail".

I hope this helps show what the issue is and you are able to see live something I am not.

******END UPDATE********

I am working on a website, and I am having an issue with my CSS not loading in certain sections.  Most of the site works great.  I am using bootstrap for responsiveness.  But there is one spot that is giving me trouble.  I have about 10 different pages that all work, that all pull from the CSS, and the page that this is from pulls from the CSS, except just this part.  Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="description" content="The Krewe of Kolosse based in Dothan, AL" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Mardi gras, mardi, gras, dothan, alabama, parade, gra" />
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>******* | Member Directory</title>
</head>

<body id="directoryP">
<!-- header -->
<div class="header">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="index"><img src="../images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
        <div class="header-top">
 <ul>
    <li><a href="{facebook group}"><i class="fb"> </i></a></li>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</ul>
</div>
        <div class="head-nav">
<span class="menu"> </span>
<ul class="cl-effect-15">
    <li id="home"><a href="index" data-hover="HOME">HOME</a></li>
    <li id="calendar"><a href="calendar" data-hover="CALENDAR">CALENDAR</a>
</li>
    <li id="ball"><a href="ball" data-hover="BALL">BALL</a></li>
    <li id="directory"><a href="directory" data-hover="MEMBER DIRECTORY">MEMBER DIRECTORY</a></li>
    <li id="members"><a href="../index" data-hover="LOGOUT">LOGOUT</a></li>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
</ul>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    <!-- script-for-nav -->
    <script>
        $( "span.menu" ).click(function() {
           $( ".head-nav ul" ).slideToggle(300, function() {
              // Animation complete.
            });
        });
    </script>
    <!-- script-for-nav --> 
</div>
</div>  
<!-- header -->
<!-- content -->
<div class="content-top">
<div class="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="contact-main">
            <h3>MEMBER DIRECTORY</h3>
            <div class="member-top">
                 <table class="member-top">
                      <tbody>
                           <tr>
                               <td class="member-top" width="75px"><h5>Member Number</h5></td>
                               <td class="member-top" width="110px"><h5>First Name</h5></td>
                               <td class="member-top" width="110px"><h5>Last Name</h5></td>
                               <td class="member-top" width="250px"><h5>Business</h5></td>
                               <td class="member-top" width="110px"><h5>Phone</h5></td>
                               <td class="member-top" width="220px"><h5>Email</h5></td>
                               <td class="member-top" width="75px"><h5>Year<br>Joined</h5></td>
                               <td class="member-top"><h5>Notes</h5></td>
                               <td class="member-top" width="75px"><h5>Status</h5></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr class="member-data">
                                <td class="member-data">1</td>
                                <td class="member-data">******</td>
                                <td class="member-data">******</td>
                                <td class="member-data">******</td>
                                <td class="member-data">(***) ***-****</td>
                                <td class="member-data">****@*****.com</td>
                                <td class="member-data">****</td>
                                <td class="member-data">*******</td>
                                <td class="member-data">*****</td>
                           </tr>
                      </tbody>
                 </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
</div>
<!-- content -->
<!-- footer -->
    <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="soc">
            <div class="social">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{facebook group}"><i class="facbk"> </i></a></li>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="foot-bottom">
            <div class="col-md-4 flick">
                <h4>SNAPSHOTS</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="./Directory-failed_files/img1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="./Directory-failed_files/img3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="./Directory-failed_files/img4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="./Directory-failed_files/img6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="./Directory-failed_files/img9.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="./Directory-failed_files/img10.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></li>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>    
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 flick1">
                <h4>POPULAR POSTS</h4>
                <div class="flick2">
                    <div class="flick-left">
                    <div class="portfolio-wrapper ">
                    <img src="./Directory-failed_files/img1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <ul class="social-ic">

                    </ul>
                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flick-right">
                        <p>Smile King!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>    
                </div>
                <div class="flick2">
                    <div class="flick-left">
                    <div class="portfolio-wrapper ">
                    <img src="./Directory-failed_files/img3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <ul class="social-ic">

                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flick-right">
                        <p>The Lovely Ladies!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 flick">
                <h4>EMAIL US</h4>
                <div class="flick-form_grid">
                   <form method="post" action="{domain}/html_float_send">
                     <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" class="textbox" value="Name" onfocus="this.value = &#39;&#39;;" onblur="if (this.value == &#39;&#39;) {this.value = &#39;Name&#39;;}">
                     <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" class="textbox" value="Email" onfocus="this.value = &#39;&#39;;" onblur="if (this.value == &#39;&#39;) {this.value = &#39;Email&#39;;}">
                     <input type="text" name="phone" maxlength="80" class="textbox" value="Phone" onfocus="this.value = &#39;&#39;;" onblur="if (this.value == &#39;&#39;) {this.value = &#39;Phone&#39;;}">
                     <input type="text" name="comments" maxlength="1000" class="textbox" value="Comments" onfocus="this.value = &#39;&#39;;" onblur="if (this.value == &#39;&#39;) {this.value = &#39;Message&#39;;}">
                     <div class="smt">
                        <input type="submit" value="email">
                     </div>
                   </form>
              </div>
            </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="footer-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="foot-left">
            <div class="foot-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{domain}/index" data-hover="HOME" title="Home Page">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{domain}/calendar" data-hover="CALENDAR" title="About Me">CALENDAR</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{domain}/index" data-hover="LEAVE" title="Members Only">LEAVE</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>                  
            </div>
            <div class="foot-right">
                <p>Copyrights © 2017 ******** All rights reserved | Website by ***** | <a href="{domain}/legal" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="{domain}legal" title="Terms and Conditions">Terms &amp; Conditions</a> </p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- footer -->

</body></html>
```

The code functions to create the table.  The data from mysql displays.  The issue is the table formatting.  The CSS formatting is not coming over.  I have the various classes created in my CSS (see below), but when I view the site, none of the formatting takes effect.  In Chrome, I use more tools -> developer tools and look to see what code is there, and the site is pulling from bootstrap css, but is not pulling from my css.

```
.member-top table {
  color: #f0f0f0;
  align: left;
  border-spacing: .8em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 10em;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1em;
}

.member-top tr {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10em;
}

.member-top td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10em;
}

.member-data tr {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10em;
}

.member-data td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10em;
}
```

I am aware that a value of 10em is rather large.  But at this point I was using a value of that size to see if any changes were being made.

Above is the code for the rendered page.  It does not create my borders or space as I want.

Below is the code that works.

```css
.member-top table {
  color: #f0f0f0;
  align: left;
  border-spacing: .8em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 10em;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1em;
}

.member-top tr {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10em;
}

.member-top td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10em;
}

.member-data tr {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10em;
}

.member-data td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="The Krewe of Kolosse based in Dothan, AL" />
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="Mardi gras, mardi, gras, dothan, alabama, parade, gra" />
  <script type="application/x-javascript">
    addEventListener("load", function() {
      setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0);
    }, false);

    function hideURLbar() {
      window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }
  </script>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>******* | Member Directory</title>
</head>

<body id="directoryP">
  <!-- header -->
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index"><img src="../images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="header-right">
        <div class="header-top">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="{facebook group}"><i class="fb"> </i></a></li>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="head-nav">
          <span class="menu"> </span>
          <ul class="cl-effect-15">
            <li id="home"><a href="index" data-hover="HOME">HOME</a></li>
            <li id="calendar"><a href="calendar" data-hover="CALENDAR">CALENDAR</a></li>
            <li id="ball"><a href="ball" data-hover="BALL">BALL</a></li>
            <li id="directory"><a href="directory" data-hover="MEMBER DIRECTORY">MEMBER DIRECTORY</a></li>
            <li id="members"><a href="../index" data-hover="LOGOUT">LOGOUT</a></li>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"> </div>
      <!-- script-for-nav -->
      <script>
        $("span.menu").click(function() {
          $(".head-nav ul").slideToggle(300, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
        });
      </script>
      <!-- script-for-nav -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- header -->
  <!-- content -->
  <div class="content-top">
    <div class="contact">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="contact-main">
          <h3>MEMBER DIRECTORY</h3>
          <div class="member-top">
            <table align="left" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8" width="100%" border="2" bordercolor="#777777">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td width="75px">
                    <h5>Member Number</h5>
                  </td>
                  <td width="110px">
                    <h5>First Name</h5>
                  </td>
                  <td width="110px">
                    <h5>Last Name</h5>
                  </td>
                  <td width="250px">
                    <h5>Business</h5>
                  </td>
                  <td width="110px">
                    <h5>Phone</h5>
                  </td>
                  <td width="220px">
                    <h5>Email</h5>
                  </td>
                  <td width="75px">
                    <h5>Year<br>Joined</h5>
                  </td>
                  <td class="member-top">
                    <h5>Notes</h5>
                  </td>
                  <td width="75px">
                    <h5>Status</h5>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>******</td>
                  <td>******</td>
                  <td>******</td>
                  <td>(***) ***-****</td>
                  <td>****@*****.com</td>
                  <td>****</td>
                  <td>*******</td>
                  <td>*****</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- content -->
  <!-- footer -->
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="soc">
        <div class="social">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="{facebook group}"><i class="facbk"> </i></a></li>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="foot-bottom">
        <div class="col-md-4 flick">
          <h4>SNAPSHOTS</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><img src="./Directory-failed_files/img1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="./Directory-failed_files/img3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="./Directory-failed_files/img4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="./Directory-failed_files/img6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="./Directory-failed_files/img9.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="./Directory-failed_files/img10.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></li>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 flick1">
          <h4>POPULAR POSTS</h4>
          <div class="flick2">
            <div class="flick-left">
              <div class="portfolio-wrapper ">
                <img src="./Directory-failed_files/img1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                <ul class="social-ic">

                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flick-right">
              <p>Smile King!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="flick2">
            <div class="flick-left">
              <div class="portfolio-wrapper ">
                <img src="./Directory-failed_files/img3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                <ul class="social-ic">

                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flick-right">
              <p>The Lovely Ladies!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 flick">
          <h4>EMAIL US</h4>
          <div class="flick-form_grid">
            <form method="post" action="{domain}/html_float_send">
              <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" class="textbox" value="Name" onfocus="this.value = &#39;&#39;;" onblur="if (this.value == &#39;&#39;) {this.value = &#39;Name&#39;;}">
              <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" class="textbox" value="Email" onfocus="this.value = &#39;&#39;;" onblur="if (this.value == &#39;&#39;) {this.value = &#39;Email&#39;;}">
              <input type="text" name="phone" maxlength="80" class="textbox" value="Phone" onfocus="this.value = &#39;&#39;;" onblur="if (this.value == &#39;&#39;) {this.value = &#39;Phone&#39;;}">
              <input type="text" name="comments" maxlength="1000" class="textbox" value="Comments" onfocus="this.value = &#39;&#39;;" onblur="if (this.value == &#39;&#39;) {this.value = &#39;Message&#39;;}">
              <div class="smt">
                <input type="submit" value="email">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="foot-left">
        <div class="foot-nav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="{domain}/index" data-hover="HOME" title="Home Page">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="{domain}/calendar" data-hover="CALENDAR" title="About Me">CALENDAR</a></li>
            <li><a href="{domain}/index" data-hover="LEAVE" title="Members Only">LEAVE</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="foot-right">
        <p>Copyrights © 2017 ******** All rights reserved | Website by ***** | <a href="{domain}/legal" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="{domain}legal" title="Terms and Conditions">Terms &amp; Conditions</a> </p>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- footer -->
</body>

</html>
```

When I hard code the table settings, it works.

Comment: instead of `.member-top table` etc. did your try: 1. `table.member-top` or 2. `div.member-top table.member-top`?

Comment: but is your CSS linked anywhere in your html?

Comment: Assuming that your CSS file is loading, your rules are probably being overridden by Bootstrap's due to [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Also, your PHP isn't relevant to the question, post just the rendered HTML.

Comment: `.member-top table` is looking for a table element with a parent element with the class member-top.. I think you've got those css definitions just backwards. `td .member-top` etc. will/should act as you expect.

Comment: To answer the question about how the css is linked, these line is in my head:

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

Deathstorm, I think I have tried that, but to be honest I am not sure.  This has been vexing me for a bit and I cannot remember all the variations I have tried.  I will try that for certain.

rlemon, you and Deathstorm seem to be on the same path.  That gives me hope that 2 guys have the same idea.

Comment: I tried the suggestion.  No joy.  Looking at the developer tools in Chrome, the only CSS that this section seems to be pulling from is one called "user agent stylesheet"  but other sections of the page are pulling from style.css (the formatting style sheet).  The only formatting from style,css the table is pulling is from inherited.

Comment: @j08691 I have edited the post to show the rendered version.  Granted, I shortened it a bit so we didn't have a ton of lines, but the idea is shown.

Comment: I would avoid using the same class name attached to multiple elements.  It looks like you are trying something close to [BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/).

Comment: Phix, I am not familiar with BEM.  I will have to research it. Thank you for the link

Comment: @Chris, I edited your post to have a runnable snippet. My answer below has a snippet with the two other code blocks in your question. Both of them appear to work just fine. I'm afraid we cannot help you if we cannot see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the update in your question, it became clear to me what is wrong.

There is an error in your stylesheet, causing the browser to parse only part of it.

Please review the [errors listed by the W3C validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kolosse.org%2Fstack%2Fcss%2Fstyle.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en#errors), fix them and all should be fine.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try to build something to create the issue.

As for the over usage of "member-data", I was hoping to be able to just use the CSS to edit <tr> and let the <td> inherit from that.  But as I began testing, and with no response, I began to add to see if the CSS formatting would show up anywhere.  My thought process was CSS <table> and <tr> using class and then just use an id for the specific columns on the first row to adjust the table sizing.  But alas, no luck so far.

Comment: I see. That makes a lot of sense, but is not how CSS works. I advise you to read some tutorials, I recommend [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS). As to creating something that demonstrates the issue: just start with your full page and try to remove as much as possible, while still keeping the issue around. Don't spend too much time getting rid of two characters here or there :-) If you do, please update your question and feel free to ping me by leaving a comment here.

Comment: While it isn't a full test, above shows two versions.  One that does not work (up top) and one that does (bottom).

Comment: It is not possible to work with your second example, as the external CSS is missing. Can you please create a snippet? It'll allow you to easily include the versions of Bootstrap and jQuery you are using. If you are unable to figure out how to do that, please let me know which versions you are using, then I'll edit your post for you :-)

Comment: Thank you.  I am not sure.  Bootstrap is v3.1.1. jQuery is v1.7.1 (jquery.min.js)

Comment: I knew I just had to ask my idiotic question in the right way.  Thanks to the master!

Comment: Nah, your question isn't idiotic at all. Plus, you helped at lot in being helped with your helpful comments and question updates. Cheers mate!

Comment: I may have spoke too soon.  I got the CSS validator to pass, and still no joy.  So, we have CSS validated.  We know it is reading some of the CSS (I can prove that due to the pink accent colors), but it is not reading the CSS for the table.  Time to do more digging.

Comment: I found the issue!!!  I had a div class ahead of the table that was causing the issue.  <div class="contact-main"> was the culprit.  I changed it to <div class="single"> and everything works just fine!  Thanks for the guidance and helping me find my way.

Comment: You are welcome, and I am very happy that you found the second issue yourself!